# Symmetric cipher

Tags: c++, algorithm, cryptography

Can someone please review this algo and say if it has some weak places and/or what kind of algo is this (caesar, block etc)?

```
std::vector<unsigned char> TestCryptDecrypt(const std::vector<unsigned char>& data, const std::vector<unsigned char>& key, bool decrypt)
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> result;
    unsigned int seed = 0, salt = 0, prev = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < key.size() - 4; i += 4)
    {
        unsigned int part = 0;
        for (int j = i; j < i + 4; j++)
            part = part << 8 | key[j];

        seed ^= part;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        unsigned char kc = key[i % key.size()];

        seed = seed * 214013 + 2531011;
        salt = ((seed >> 16) + kc) % 256;

        unsigned int enc = data[i] ^ kc ^ salt;
        result.push_back(enc);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The key can be of any length, usually 32 bytes

Comment: Asking about the type of cipher is a little odd, did you write this code?

Comment: Without a thorough analysis, yes, this is a very weak cipher because each encrypted byte is linearly derived from the key and the cleartext.

Comment: How would you charge it to make it stronger?

Comment: I'd use AES instead.

Comment: Is there any other simple but strong enough algo?

Comment: @AlekDepler When it comes to cryptography there is a general rule if you want to make something secure: Don't make it yourself. The existing algorithms are there for a reason.

Comment: @AlekDepler: The obvious question would be: "strong enough...for what?" There are well known algorithms covering a huge range of strength levels, all the way from maybe enough to discourage somebody from reading your diary (or whatever) all the way to the *only* way to get your data being to force you to give up the password. The question is: what do you really want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a substitution-based stream cipher.

Like most stream ciphers, it's *extremely* vulnerable<sup>1</sup> if you ever re-use a key.

Given how you generate `seed` from your key, it also becomes quite vulnerable if there's repetition *inside* of a single key. You XOR 32-bit chunks together, so (for example) a key like "ABCDABCD" will give a seed of `0`.

At least as I read things, you're assuming that `key` will be a 32-bit type (though it could be any size greater than or equal to 16 bits). This means only \$2^{32}-1\$ values of `key` are possible. This is a small enough number that it's open to (easy) brute-force attack--that is, somebody can easily just try every possible value for `seed`.

That leaves them with the task of choosing among the ~4 billion results of those. For the correct value of `seed`, they'll get a stream that's just the XOR of one byte of plain text with one byte of raw key (i.e., a basic Vernam cipher).

That leaves them with the task of choosing which of those for billion choices is the correct one. For this part of the attack, they'd most likely use the [IC](http://practicalcryptography.com/cryptanalysis/text-characterisation/index-coincidence/) or [Kasiski test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasiski_examination).

Either of these will tell them (with very high probability) both which of the 4 billion choices for `seed` is correct, *and* the length of input you used for `key`.

From there, it's pretty much all downhill, and a fairly steep hill at that. Basically, they section the cipher text into N bins (where N is the length of the key), and do basic frequency analysis on it to figure out which character in the cipher text is substituted for which character in the input.

100 years ago, this would have qualified as *sort of* secure, but considerably better techniques were known. A skilled attacker could have broken it, but it probably would have taken at least a few days to do it.

By World War II cryptanalysts routinely broke much more secure algorithms than this in a matter of minutes or hours.

On a current computer, even a very simple attack could break this in a matter of seconds.

---

<sup>1. In this case, "extremely vulnerable" basically translates to: "it's immediately broken".</sup>

Comment: Wow man, you are cool )) Can you advise some simple but strong enough cipher (not AES/two fish/serpent). Is it possible to change this algo to make it stronger? What if I would use 8 seeds instead of 1?

Comment: @AlekDepler: For something at least sort of close to secure (but still pretty simple) you might consider [TEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm) or [XTEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA). If you prefer to continue with a stream cipher, perhaps [ARC4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4). It's not really secure, but at least requires fairly sophisticated attacks to break it.

Comment: If the objection to using AES is that it's too large or complex, the first thing would be to consider would be add sufficient hardware (many modern chips have AES capabilities built in).  If there is *really* a reason not to use it, e.g. you're creating an embedded device which must run on a single AA battery for 20 years, then you might wish to read about the [Lightweight Cryptography](https://www.nist.gov/programs-projects/lightweight-cryptography) project at NIST.